# Packaged Spring boot application doesnt resolve rest api errors to a message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where I am currently running it with `mvnw spring-boot:run`
I have setup a custom exception like so

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class InvalidEntityException extends Exception {

    public InvalidEntityException() {
        super();
    }

    public InvalidEntityException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public InvalidEntityException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public InvalidEntityException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

In a method in a rest controller I can throw this exception and in the Spring Boot logs I can see
`Resolved [foo.bar.InvalidEntityException: Error message.]`

And in the JSON response my data looks like this:

```
error: "Bad Request"
message: "Error message"
path: "/resource/request"
status: 400
timestamp: "2021-06-06T04:12:39.759+00:00"
```

However, when I go and run `mvn clean package` and run my output .jar file using `java -jar out.jar` and call a method on this controller, I no longer see the message `Resolved [foo.bar.InvalidEntityException: Error message.]` and my JSON response looks like this, with the message missing.

```
error: "Bad Request"
message: ""
path: "/resource/request"
status: 400
timestamp: "2021-06-06T04:12:39.759+00:00"
```

What is the difference between running my springboot application from `mvnw spring-boot:run` to running the .jar? I want the same behaviour where error messages are resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are using Spring Boot’s devtools module. It is designed to make application development easier and is automatically disabled when running your application as a packaged jar.

Devtools sets `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception` to `true`. This causes `Resolved [foo.bar.InvalidEntityException: Error message.]` to be logged.

Devtools also sets `server.error.include-message` to `ALWAYS`. This causes the exception message to be included in the error response. In a non-development environment, you should set this property with caution. You need to be certain that none of your application’s exception messages will leak information that you would not want a malicious client to see.